# React Router - Cannot GET

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router

I have created simple web application running on a MERN stack, I have just tried to set up my routing with react-router. Now I know this question has been asked before but answers were suggesting adding options to Webpack whereas I am using Browserify / Gulp.

My problem is that my all my routes except for root are returning with CANNOT get.

```
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var Redirect = require('react-router').Redirect;
var browserHistory = require('react-router').browserHistory;

class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/bugs" component={BugList} />
          <Redirect from="/" to="/bugs"/>
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I believe you need to import the components you're routing to. So for example:

```
var BugList = require('./components/bugList');
```

Also, I think you can remove the slashes except for the root route. So this should work:

```
<Route path="bugs" component={BugList} />
```

Comment: ok so I didn't paste in the required components as I thought this was too much code for SO. However I am indeed requiring all components.

The slashes are not the problem, this issue is somewhere within my Express server